# Meteorjs with ta-lib npm module (server side)

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, ta-lib

I would like to use [npm talib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/talib) module within a meteorjs application.
I followed the instruction [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) and I added this to the `packages.json` file:

```
{
  "talib" :   "0.6.0"
}
```

After running `meteor` the module `talib.node` is there in the `node_modules/talib/build/Release/` folder.
Then I wrote the following:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var Talib = Meteor.npmRequire('talib');
  var talib = new Talib();
}
```

The `Talib` object is created and can be logged, like this:

```
{ version: '0.6.0',
  functions: 
  [ { name: 'ADD',
     group: 'Math Operators',
     ...
     }
  ],
  functionUnstIds: 
   { TA_FUNC_UNST_ADX: 0,
     TA_FUNC_UNST_ADXR: 1,
     ...
   }
 }
```

The line `var talib = new Talib()` gives instead this error:

```
 TypeError: object is not a function
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it's obvious with the log: You don't have a function but an object with multiple fields (`versions`, `functions`...). Calling `new` with that object is going to fail. I'm not sure if this is because the NPM library has not been imported correctly using `Meteor` or if it's an issue with the library API, since I have not worked with either ones.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works as an object; I can call properties and methods directly on the object returned from `var talib = Meteor.npmRequire('talib');`, as `console.log("TALib Version: " + talib.version);`